# ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()

Tags: android, android-activity, androidx

In androidx.activity version 1.2.0-alpha05 API for TakePicture contract has been changed:

> The TakePicture contract now returns a boolean indicating success rather than a thumbnail Bitmap as this was very rarely supported by camera apps when writing the image to the provided Uri

While in alpha04 callback received a Bitmap object, now only a Boolean object that describes success is received by the callback.

So now the Uri Parameter of the launch method of the launcher must not be null, but must be the destination where the picture is saved. Did not manage to create an Uri object that is accepted by the launcher and that can be used for my app to read the result picture.

Does anybody have an example for me for a valid Uri object that can be provided to the launcher?

Comment: Use `FileProvider`.

Answer (score 25):

I can't find any example on the internet
Here is an example.

```java
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "picFromCamera");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                            
        // do what you need with the uri here ...
    }
});                        
mGetContent.launch(uri);
```

Note1: You are likely to run into `FileUriExposedException` , need to expose this uri for the camera app to access

Related: [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Note2: If you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` declared in your manifest, you need to have permission before launching, otherwise `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial`

Comment: Have you tried this? You'll probably get an IllegalStateException with the message: YourFragment is attempting to registerForActivityResult after being created. But perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: In fragments, you should register your ActivitiesResultLaunchers in onAttach or onCreate method

Comment: Not a well explained answer, you should have added some more details, for whether to place above two lines of file and uri.

Comment: Note: if you are doing this from a fragment, use `requireActivity()` instead of `this`.

Comment: What is `my.package.provider`? Do I need to create a Provider for this and declare it in my AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Also from a fragment, use `requireActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName()`. Or alternatively, `requireActivity().getPackageName()`. Or `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.

Answer (score 2):

thanks @babyishTank for good answer, after adding following changes works for me

```
    val directory = File(context.filesDir, "camera_images")
    if(!directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdirs()
    }
    val file = File(directory,"${Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis}.png")
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                            
        // do what you need with the uri here ...
    }
});                        
mGetContent.launch(uri);
```

and in **filepaths.xml** add following code

```
<files-path
    name="images"
    path="camera_images/"/>
```