# Why is android invalidating a valid file when data is saved to it

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to store a camera image to a temporary file to be used in a network task.  I successfully create the file and pass the Uri into the activity.  However, when the camera image is taken, a debug message I added says the file does not exist, even though another debug message right before the picture was taken says the file exists.  My current code to handle the camera interaction is as such:

manifest:

```
<provider
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
       android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <root-path name="root" path="."/>
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

activity:

```
private fun prepURI(): Uri { //create a temporary file and return the file's Uri
    val path = File(filesDir, "my_images")
    if(!path.exists()) { path.mkdirs(); println("Path Does Not Exist!") }        
    val imgFile = File.createTempFile("IMG_",".jpg", path)
    Log.d("Camera_Log", "image ${imgFile.name} ${ if(imgFile.exists()) "exists" else "doesn't exist"}")
    return getUriForFile(this, "${this.packageName}.provider", imgFile)
}

private fun registerLauncher() { //create activityResultLauncher for camera
    launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { isSaved ->
        if (isSaved) {
            val file = File(imageUri.path!!)
            Log.d("Camera_Log", "image ${file.name} ${ if(file.exists()) "exists" else "doesn't exist"}")
        }
    } 
}

private fun handleCamera() { //check permissions and launch camera with Uri from prepURI()
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
    } else launcher.launch(imageUri)
}

/*Handle Camera Permisssions*/
```

The Logcat Output shows that the first `println()` says that the file does exist but the second one says it doesn't.  The filename in both of the prints is the same.

I have looked at question [ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture returns "No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65751435) to ensure that I am providing a valid Uri to the system.  I have also ensured that the directories for the file path exist.

Comment: Have you tried a minimal example reproducing this issue?

Comment: Yes.  Running similar code in a new android test project returned similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the final image is different than before, but the Uri does point to the same resource.  A library like Picasso is able to load the Uri and display the image successfully.