# Android Java - how to use ActivityResultContracts.GetContent

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have been desperately searching throughout the internet of a semi-complete example of how to use this in Java. Nearly all the examples I can find are in Kotlin, eg

`registerForActivityResult(GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->`

But I can't use that syntax in Java. The closest I've found is this: [ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941959/activityresultcontracts-takepicture), but this isn't for the `GetContent()` contract, it's for `TakePicture()` and it's not working for me.

How can I register for the GetContent activity result using Java?

[edit] seems all my problems may have been solved by adding `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1` and using the examples [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: The docs you've linked have both Kotlin and Java examples for a reason :)

Comment: The ones I mentioned in my edit, where I mentioned that my problems were solved? Yeah, good catch.